# API gateway and DynamoDB integration - SerializationException

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

I have setup an API endpoint integration to DynamoDB.
I want to query a table using query string parameter as query filter.
Unfortunatley I ended up getting error:

```
Method response body after transformations: {"__type":"com.amazon.coral.service#SerializationException"}
```

with no clue what is the root cause.

To do the stated above I have taken the following steps:

1) Setup a get method in API gateway

[image]

2) In the Method Request I added a parameter to URL Query String Parameters
[image]

3) In the integration request I added the same parameter from step 2 in URL Query String Parameters
[image]

4)In DynamoDB table I decalred a new index for the column that I'd like to query

5)In body mapping template:

```
{
    "TableName": "tjusers",
    "IndexName" "badge-index",
    "KeyConditionExpression": "badge = :v1",
    "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
        ":v1": {
            "S": "$input.params('badge')"
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

THe exception:

```
xecution log for request f0081606-b521-11e8-adb2-cd8092221b33
Mon Sep 10 17:50:00 UTC 2018 : Starting execution for request: f0081606-b521-11e8-adb2-cd8092221b33
Mon Sep 10 17:50:00 UTC 2018 : HTTP Method: GET, Resource Path: /db/users
Mon Sep 10 17:50:00 UTC 2018 : Method request path: {}
Mon Sep 10 17:50:00 UTC 2018 : Method request query string: {badge=18323}
Mon Sep 10 17:50:00 UTC 2018 : Method request headers: {}
Mon Sep 10 17:50:00 UTC 2018 : Method request body before transformations: 
Mon Sep 10 17:50:00 UTC 2018 : Endpoint request URI: https://dynamodb.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/?Action=Query&badge=11111
Mon Sep 10 17:50:00 UTC 2018 : Endpoint request headers: {Authorization=****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************feb2ac, X-Amz-Date=20180910T175000Z, x-amzn-apigateway-api-id=53zgcztitj, Accept=application/json, User-Agent=AmazonAPIGateway_53zgcztitj, X-Amz-Security-Token=AgoGb3JpZ2l....
Mon Sep 10 17:50:00 UTC 2018 : Endpoint request body after transformations: {
    "TableName": "tjusers",
    "IndexName" "badge-index",
    "KeyConditionExpression": "badge = :v1",
    "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
        ":v1": {
            "S": "11111"
        }
    }
}

Mon Sep 10 17:50:00 UTC 2018 : Sending request to https://dynamodb.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/?Action=Query&badge=18323
Mon Sep 10 17:50:00 UTC 2018 : Received response. Integration latency: 11 ms
Mon Sep 10 17:50:00 UTC 2018 : Endpoint response body before transformations: {"__type":"com.amazon.coral.service#SerializationException"}
Mon Sep 10 17:50:00 UTC 2018 : Endpoint response headers: {Server=Server, Date=Mon, 10 Sep 2018 17:49:59 GMT, Content-Type=application/x-amz-json-1.0, Content-Length=60, Connection=keep-alive, x-amzn-RequestId=ODMJ814D1GBN875T6MTR7BUHGVVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG, x-amz-crc32=3948637019}
Mon Sep 10 17:50:00 UTC 2018 : Method response body after transformations: {"__type":"com.amazon.coral.service#SerializationException"}
Mon Sep 10 17:50:00 UTC 2018 : Method response headers: {X-Amzn-Trace-Id=Root=1-5b96aec8-addec09261723342f53a179f, Content-Type=application/json}
Mon Sep 10 17:50:00 UTC 2018 : Successfully completed execution
Mon Sep 10 17:50:00 UTC 2018 : Method completed with status: 200
```

Comment: It might be helpful to iterate your troubleshooting to involve [temporarily] not using an Index or URL Query String, in an effort to reduce some variables here.

Answer (score 6):

You are missing `:` after "IndexName", that cause SerializationException

[image]

Comment: I had a similar syntax error but couldn't see it in the API Gateway console. I recommend copying your JSON into an editor to make sure it's valid.

Answer (score 0):

What is the schema of your `tjusers` DynamoDB Table?
In particular, what is the datatype of `badge`?  If it is Number, for example, you need to be using `"N"` instead of `"S"`.

(In general, here is a recent new tutorial that meets your requirements and has more details/screenshots than I've seen in others: https://medium.com/@likhita507/using-api-gateway-to-get-data-from-dynamo-db-using-without-using-aws-lambda-e51434a4f5a0)