# AWS API Gateway and DynamoDb Serialization Exception Response Codes

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk, clouddevelopmentkit

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52263118/api-gateway-and-dynamodb-integration-serializationexception) resolves how to fix serializaion errors caused by a bad template, but if they are cause by input errors like a missing param, they are returned with a 200.

I'm trying to add a response template for errors using the CDK on an DynamoDb integration

```
 read_integration_responses=[aws_apigateway.IntegrationResponse(
                        status_code="200",
                        response_templates= {"application/json":read_response_template}),
                        aws_apigateway.IntegrationResponse(status_code="400",
                                                            response_templates={"text/html": "Client Error"},
                                                             selection_pattern="400" )
                        ])
```

The 200 works fine, but I get a 500 server error when I have an error.  The logs are no help:

> Fri Feb 10 21:37:37 UTC 2023 : Sending request to
> https://dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/?Action=Query Fri Feb 10
> 21:37:37 UTC 2023 : Received response. Status: 400, Integration
> latency: 6 ms Fri Feb 10 21:37:37 UTC 2023 : Endpoint response
> headers: {Server=Server, Date=Fri, 10 Feb 2023 21:37:37 GMT,
> Content-Type=application/x-amz-json-1.0, Content-Length=60,
> Connection=keep-alive,
> x-amzn-RequestId=HB4E7S3FS0NIMM44OQRN6RPBEBVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG,
> x-amz-crc32=3948637019} Fri Feb 10 21:37:37 UTC 2023 : Endpoint
> response body before transformations:
> {"__type":"com.amazon.coral.service#SerializationException"} Fri Feb
> 10 21:37:37 UTC 2023 : Execution failed due to configuration error:
> Output mapping refers to an invalid method response: 400 Fri Feb 10
> 21:37:37 UTC 2023 : Method completed with status: 500

Per the method [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_apigateway.IntegrationResponse.html#selectionpattern) selection_pattern is a string that matches the response code.